# Am I speaking with both head and chest voice since I am a tenor?

Tags: voice

I have heard people saying that chest voice is easier than head voice. I even met a vocal teacher who said that speak in chest voice. I told her it is not true for me. 
When I speak naturally I use both chest and head voice. The vocal teacher told me that I could be a tenor (which was later confirmed). 
Am I speaking with both head and chest voice since I am a tenor? 
What does the vocal science have to say about this?

Comment: Do you detect a chest-head voice split when you speak, or do you speak in mixed voice?

Comment: Mixing them both